# Impala query to get sample value of column used in count aggregate function

Tags: hive, impala

I have huge data in hive table. PFB sample rows.

Table:

```
Clid,pid,lid
1 ,1 ,OJA
1 ,2 , KLM
1, 2 , MHK
1 ,2, DNY
```

I want to write impala query to get count of lid for each clid,pid group along with sample value.
I know how to get count but how can I get sample value of lid for each clid, pid group.

`Select clid, pid, count(lid) frim t group by clid,pid`

What should I add in impala query to get sample lid as shown in below result.

Expected result:

```
Clid, pid, count, sample lid
1, 1, 1, OJA
1, 2,3,MHK
```

I have tried using first_val function with over clause but it's giving error.

`select clid,pid, count (lid), first_value(lid) over (partition by clid, pid) from t group by clid, pid`

Error:

AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?):
first_value(lid) OVER (PARTITION BY clid,pid)

Comment: What error are you receiving? Please include your attempt with the first_val function

Comment: @{ggordon} I have added my first_val query with error in above post

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `first_value`, a window function will produce a value for each row and is not included in your group by clause as a field to group on.

Since there is no explicit ordering on how you retrieve the `sample_lid` using your first_val function (i.e. including an `ORDER BY some_field` in the over clause) you may use the MAX function instead in your aggregation to extract a `sample_lid` eg

```sql
select clid,pid, COUNT(lid), MAX(lid) as sample_lid
from t 
group by clid, pid
```

If you are indeed interest in using the first_value function by some ordering you could modify your query to add an `ORDER BY to the over clause` and/or use `row_number` to filter based on the first row.

Let me know if thus works for you.